# Segmentation fault on char string reference

Tags: c, character

I have a small C++ function which reverses a string in place:

```
void reverse1(string& s, int start, int end) {
  if (s.empty()) return;
  char tmp;

  while (start < end) {
    tmp = s[end];
    s[end] = s[start];
    s[start] = tmp;
    ++start;
    --end;
  }
}
```

This function works fine. However, when I rewrite it in c as below, I came across a segment fault on statement 11.

```
  5 void reverse2(char *s, int start, int end) {
  6   if (!s) return;
  7   char tmp;
  8   
  9   while (start < end) {
 10     tmp = s[end];
 11     *(s + end) = *(s + start);
 12     *(s + start) = tmp;
 13     ++start;
 14     --end;
 15   } 
 16 }
```

Driver program that calls the function:

```
int main() {
  /* Flavor1 works */
  string a = "hello world2012!";
  reverse1(a, 0, a.length() - 1);

  /* Flavor2 does not - segmentation fault */ 
  char *b = "hello world2012!";
  reverse2(b, 0, strlen(b) - 1);
}
```

I use gcc v 4.6.1 to compile my program. When stepping through the code with gdb, the program crashes at runtime with segmentation fault.

The char string s is not a const. Can someone please suggest what's going on here? How do I fix this issue. Thanks.

Update:
The reverse2 function is called on a string literal. The problem is I was trying to modify the string literal. As Jim and H2CO3 pointed out, this is an undefined behavior.

Now what's the exact difference between a string object (a) initialized with a string literal and a string literal (b)?

Comment: You know you can use `s[end]` and `s[start]` in C, right?

Comment: Try `s[end] = s[start];` etc rather than getting into explicit pointer arithmetic.

Comment: If you weren't aware, C++ has `std::reverse` to do that. I'd recommend that over using your own when using C++.

Comment: Your function looks OK, *provided* that `start` and `end` are valid string indices and `s` is a writable string -- you might want to check the function's caller. Also note that `!s` just checks to see if `s` is a NULL pointer, not to see if `s` is an empty string; you'd need `!s[0]` for that.

Comment: You should post how the reverse function is invoked, how the string is built and the values of the start and end indexes to help you better.

Comment: I bet you're calling your function on a string literal...

Comment: @nneonneo: I tried using s[end] and s[start]. It failed the same way.

Comment: 'Now what's the exact difference between a string object (a) initialized with a string literal and a string literal (b)?' -- The same as the difference between a buffer to which a string literal has been copied, and a string literal.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is that possible to reverse the char string literal in place ? i.e. without copying the literal to a string object? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you invoke your routine. If `end` is the length of the array, as is common in C, then `s[end]` is not a valid reference ... it's one character beyond `s`.

Also, `!s` is not equivalent to C++ `s.empty` ... it tests whether the pointer is NULL, rather than whether the string is empty -- for that, use `!*s`, `!s[0]`, `s[0] == '\0'`, `strlen(s) == 0`, etc.

> The char string s is not a const.

It could fail anyway if it's a string literal constant; writing to such a string is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that the top condition can be `s && s[0]` (or any variant) to make sure it isn't a null pointer and has a string contained.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the code as below

```
void reverse(char *s, int start, int end) {
  if (!s) return;
  char tmp;

  if( end >= strlen(s) )
      end = strlen(s)-1;

  while (start < end) {
    tmp = s[end];
    *(s + end) = *(s + start);
    *(s + start) = tmp;
    ++start;
    --end;
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's the point? All that does is hide a bug if `end` is wrong; it's very bad practice. Better would be `assert(start >= 0 && end < strlen(s))`, but it's extravagant and isn't the OP's problem. And if you're going to rewrite it, replace the pointlessly verbose `*(s + x)` with `s[x]`.